# Spin about an arbitrary axis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

This is based off question 4.30 from Griffith's *Introduction to Quanum Mechanics*. It asks for the matrix $\textbf{S}_r$ representing the component of spin angular momentum about an axis defined by: $$r = \sin{\theta}\cos{\phi}\hat{i}+\sin\theta\sin\phi\hat{j}+\cos\theta\hat{k}$$

for a spin = $1/2$ particle.The problem is, I can't visualize how the spin vectors relate to spatial coordinates. $$\chi_+ = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\ \text{ and } \chi_- = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}. $$

So these form a basis of some kind of space, but this is a space I don't understand, for example, why does: 
$$\chi^{(x)}_+ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\1 \end{pmatrix} ?$$

I was going to try to use a rotation matrix with angles corresponding to my axis of rotation to try and "rotate" the spin vector onto it, but then I realized that not only do the dimensions not match up, but the angle is π/4, which doesn't make much sense to me. So I guess my question is, how does the 'geometry' of spin work and how can I transform the spins corresponding to a transform I do in space?

Thanks.

Comment: Spin-1/2 representation of rotations involve the [Pauli matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). More details about the physics [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_%28physics%29#Mathematical_formulation_of_spin).

Comment: You may also want to look up the [Bloch sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere), which is the canonical geometric incarnation of the state space of a two-level system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Great and important question; I hope this response is illuminating and encourages you and others to explore [Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and their representations](http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0005032).

When you want to rotate a vector $\mathbf v$ in three dimensions, then you act on that vector with a rotation matrix $R$ to obtain a rotated vector $\mathbf v'$ related to the original vector by
$$
  \mathbf v' = R\mathbf v
$$
It is a mathematical fact that every rotation (special orthogonal transformation) $R$ is a rotation by some angle $\theta$ about some axis defined by a unit vector $\mathbf n$, and that each such rotation can be written as the matrix exponential of a particular linear combination of certain 3-by-3 matrices $J_i$ called rotation [generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra#Generators_and_dimension).  Explicitly
$$
  R(\theta, \mathbf n) = e^{-i\theta n_i J_i}, \qquad (J_i)_{jk} = i\epsilon_{ijk}
$$
So we can write the rotation of a vector as
$$
  \mathbf v' = e^{-i\theta n_i J_i} \mathbf v
$$
It turns out, that we can *define* the rotation of spinors in an analogous way.  Instead of the rotation generators $J_i$ which are 3-by-3 matrices, we choose the pauli matrices which are 2-by-2, and for a given spinor $\xi$, we define a rotated spinor by
$$
  \chi' = e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2} n_i\sigma_i}\chi
$$
Notice how this is basically the same as rotating a vector in 3 dimensions, it's just that we have *represented* rotations acting on the vector space of spinors in a different way.

The math behind all of this is called [representation theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory).  In particular, when we are talking about spin, the representation theory is related to that of the [Lie group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group)s $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ and $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ and their so-called [Lie algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra)s and their [representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_of_a_Lie_group).

Comment: Thank you for this answer, is the $\theta$ in $X'=e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}n_i\sigma_i}X$ in "physical" space or "spinor" space?

Comment: @MikeFlynn My Pleasure.  That's another great question, and there is more than one way to think of $\theta$.  Here's one you may like.  Consider the state $\chi_{z,+}$, the eigenvector of $S_z$ corresponding to spin up.  If you apply $e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}n_i\sigma_i}$ to $\chi_{z,+}$ with $\mathbf n = \mathbf e_y$ and $\theta = \pi/2$, then you will get $\chi_{x,+}$, the spin up eigenstate of $S_x$, so in a sense, doing the rotation on the spin state corresponds to doing a physical rotation on the spin the three-dimensional world.  There is a lot more one can say here to get more intuition

Comment: (contd.) for what the rotation angle means and how rotating the spin state relates to the real world; perhaps you should ask another question about this that would address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the $z$ basis, any spinor of the form
$$ s=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \begin{bmatrix} e^{i\alpha} \\ e^{i\beta}\end{bmatrix} $$
can be an $x$ basis vactor. If we measure $s$ along the $z$ axis, we have 50%-50% chance to get up or down spins. Hence, $s$ is in the $xy$ plane. It is our choice how we want to define the basis vector.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is,
> I can't visualize how the spin vectors relate to spatial coordinates.

A spinor is a "vector" with two complex components.
$$\chi = \begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \end{pmatrix}
= a \chi_+ + b \chi_-$$

From such a spinor you can always calculate the following 3D vector (i.e. with three real components):
$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{n}
 &= \langle\chi|\boldsymbol{\sigma}|\chi\rangle \\
 &= \langle\chi|(\sigma_x\hat{\mathbf{i}}+\sigma_y\hat{\mathbf{j}}+\sigma_z\hat{\mathbf{k}})|\chi\rangle \\
 &= \langle\chi|\sigma_x|\chi\rangle \hat{\mathbf{i}}
  + \langle\chi|\sigma_y|\chi\rangle \hat{\mathbf{j}}
  + \langle\chi|\sigma_z|\chi\rangle \hat{\mathbf{k}} \\
 &= \begin{pmatrix}a^*&b^*\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}0& 1\\1&0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix} \hat{\mathbf{i}}
  + \begin{pmatrix}a^*&b^*\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}0&-i\\i&0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix} \hat{\mathbf{j}}
  + \begin{pmatrix}a^*&b^*\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1& 0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix} \hat{\mathbf{k}} \\
 &= (a^*b+b^*a) \hat{\mathbf{i}} + (-ia^*b+ib^*a) \hat{\mathbf{j}} + (a^*a-b^*b) \hat{\mathbf{k}}
\end{align}$$

When the spinor $\chi$ is normalized, then the vector $\mathbf{n}$ is a unit vector.
You can visualize it as being the axis of rotation of the spinning particle.

Examples:

- for $\chi=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$
  you get $\mathbf{n}=\hat{\mathbf{k}}$,
- for $\chi=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$
  you get $\mathbf{n}=-\hat{\mathbf{k}}$,
- for $\chi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$
  you get $\mathbf{n}=\hat{\mathbf{i}}$.